# Run a regression with data from different measurements

Tags: least-squares, cross-section, subsampling

I have a population $N$, that can be divided into several samples. 1 sample, $S$, was taken out from $N$, let's say a piece of paper from a page of a manuscript; this piece of paper is divided into three equal parts and send it to three laboratories, which divided the paper received into smaller pieces. The three laboratories study separately their pieces and try to date the page of the manuscript; each laboratory produced 3 data measurement of the page.

Finally I have 3 data measurement from each laboratory, and I want to run a regression pooling the 9 measurament. My first question is: what kind of data are these? I was thinking of pooled cross-section, but there isn't a different period of time but only different labs.

My second question is, if I want to study how the data measurement responds to different laboratories (because I want to check if there are differences in the procedure), it makes sense to use a regression like

$MEASUREMENT= a +b*D+e$

where D is a dummy which takes value one if the lab is, for example, in Europe, and zero if it is in another continent?

Comment: It would be helpful if you articulate the research question more clearly... Are you trying to ask about the reliability of the assessments? Is the question one of consistency of the results across the labs?

Comment: You totally get the point. Unfortunately I have not other data therefore I came up with the idea of a pooled regression with a dummy trying to understand if the different location of the labs impacts on the assessment. My alternative is to create two dummies, one for lab A and one for lab B (or B and C or A and C).